# Where to put preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating two selects, prodSelect and calcSelect. What I want to do is if prodSelect is not empty it should prevent calcSelect from being able to changed. Am I putting preventDefault in the wrong spot? I have tried some different solutions but I think I may be the closest with this one. 
Here is some HTML and my current jQuery.

HTML

```
<div class="col third">
  <label>Choose Calculator</label>
    <select name="calc" id="calcSelect">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="concrete">Concrete</option>
      <option value="round">Post Setting</option>
      <option value="filling">Filling</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="col third split">
  <label>Choose Product</label>
    <select name="prod" id="prodSelect">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="high-strength">High Strength</option>
      <option value="five-thousand-plus">5000 Mix</option>
      <option value="crack-resistant">Crack Resistant</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $("#calcSelect").on("change", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert( e.isDefaultPrevented() ); == true

    var rex = $('#prodSelect').val();
    var calc = $("#calcSelect option:selected").val();

    if(rex != '' && $("#calcSelect option").is(":selected")){
      calc = '';
    }
});
```

EDITED

After trying some solutions I came up with this:

```
function checkProd(){
  var rex = $('#prodSelect').val();
  var calc = $("#calcSelect option:selected").val();

    if(rex != ''){
      $("#calcSelect").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
      $("#calcSelect").prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

However, now it will not properly enable if the prodSelect value is empty...

Comment: Not sure who’s down-voting here, but would appreciate it if they bothered to leave some feedback.

Comment: not sure who is downvoting either...but i tried both solutions given and they work for the most part! however, calcSelect stays disabled and i can't figure out how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.on("change", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
```

will *prevent* the default (browser) behaviours, but *only after* the user changed something already in the rendered DOM (browser UI), hence it **does not prevent the *change* itself**, but only the consequent automatic actions triggered by a *change*.

What you want to do is to listen on attempts to change (e.g. `click`) and prevent that.

A better approach is to set the `<select>` to **readonly**, when the `.val()` of the other select is empty (`""`):

```
$('#prodSelect').on('change', 
  event => $('#calcSelect').attr(
    'readonly',
    $(this).val() === ""
      ? false
      : true
  )
);
```

PS - `readonly` is preferable than `disabled`, as that would prevent the form from submitting its value.

Answer (score -1):

`preventDefault()` only works to prevent something from running its default behaviour. For example, a form from submitting when it is submitted. It is linked to behaviour or an event.

To disable something, you‘ll need to disable it.

```
$('#prodSelect').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

This would disable `#prodSelect`.

Answer (score -1):

The way to prevent calcSelect from being changed is to do

```
document.getElementById('calcSelect').disabled = true;
```

You can also style the select box in its disabled state using CSS if you want